# Incorrect memory access: why is my kernel *not* crashing

Tags: c, linux, memory-management, linux-kernel, kernel

I wanted to show to somebody an exemple of incorrect memory access (kernelspace trying to access userspace memory leading to a bug).

Thus, I took an old tutorial as a POC, the important part is :

```c
static ssize_t dev_write(struct file *filep, const char *buffer, size_t len, loff_t *offset){
   sprintf(message, "%s(%zu letters)", buffer, len);   // appending received string with its length
   // [...]
}
```

This causes a crash in one of my environment tests, which is the expected behavior (I access the buffer which is an **userspace** variable without using `cpoy_*_user` functions thus the memory protection mechanism is trigerred and my process is killed.

But in another machine, this snippet actually works fine which seems really odd to me. Both machines uses a 5.3 kernel with a quite similar kernel configuration.

Is the VM that does not crash broken ? Is my code actually an UB? Am I missing something?

After checking in gdb, i'm really accessing a buffer-variable within gdb which is not mmapped...:

```
gdb-peda$ hb dev_write
gdb-peda$ c
Thread 3 hit Breakpoint 1, dev_write () at /home/user/testMmap/ebbchar.c:144
144     static ssize_t dev_write(struct file *filep, const char *buffer, size_t len, loff_t *offset)
gdb-peda$ x/x $rip
0xffffffffc010d000 <dev_write>: 0x0f
gdb-peda$ x/s buffer
0x56139a0e5650: "a\n"
gdb-peda$ maintenance info sections
Exec file:
    `/home/max/prog/kgdb/remote/vmlinux', file type elf64-x86-64.
 [0]     0xffffffff81000000->0xffffffff81c04371 at 0x00200000: .text ALLOC LOAD RELOC READONLY CODE HAS_CONTENTS
 [1]     0xffffffff81c04374->0xffffffff81c0456c at 0x00e04374: .notes ALLOC LOAD RELOC READONLY DATA HAS_CONTENTS
 [2]     0xffffffff81c04570->0xffffffff81c08188 at 0x00e04570: __ex_table ALLOC LOAD RELOC READONLY DATA HAS_CONTENTS
 [3]     0xffffffff81e00000->0xffffffff82154f32 at 0x01000000: .rodata ALLOC LOAD RELOC DATA HAS_CONTENTS
 [4]     0xffffffff82154f40->0xffffffff82157af0 at 0x01354f40: .pci_fixup ALLOC LOAD RELOC READONLY DATA HAS_CONTENTS
 [5]     0xffffffff82157af0->0xffffffff82160b18 at 0x01357af0: __ksymtab ALLOC LOAD RELOC READONLY DATA HAS_CONTENTS
 [6]     0xffffffff82160b18->0xffffffff82169090 at 0x01360b18: __ksymtab_gpl ALLOC LOAD RELOC READONLY DATA HAS_CONTENTS
 [7]     0xffffffff82169090->0xffffffff8216d8a4 at 0x01369090: __kcrctab ALLOC LOAD RELOC READONLY DATA HAS_CONTENTS
 [8]     0xffffffff8216d8a4->0xffffffff82171b60 at 0x0136d8a4: __kcrctab_gpl ALLOC LOAD RELOC READONLY DATA HAS_CONTENTS
 [9]     0xffffffff82171b60->0xffffffff8219c23c at 0x01371b60: __ksymtab_strings ALLOC LOAD READONLY DATA HAS_CONTENTS
 [10]     0xffffffff8219c240->0xffffffff8219e478 at 0x0139c240: __param ALLOC LOAD RELOC READONLY DATA HAS_CONTENTS
 [11]     0xffffffff8219e478->0xffffffff8219f000 at 0x0139e478: __modver ALLOC LOAD RELOC READONLY DATA HAS_CONTENTS
 [12]     0xffffffff82200000->0xffffffff82349a00 at 0x01400000: .data ALLOC LOAD RELOC DATA HAS_CONTENTS
 [13]     0xffffffff82349a00->0xffffffff8235d2a8 at 0x01549a00: __bug_table ALLOC LOAD RELOC DATA HAS_CONTENTS in
 [14]     0xffffffff8235d2a8->0xffffffff824a7e28 at 0x0155d2a8: .orc_unwind_ip ALLOC LOAD RELOC READONLY DATA HAS_CONTENTS
 [15]     0xffffffff824a7e28->0xffffffff82697f68 at 0x016a7e28: .orc_unwind ALLOC LOAD READONLY DATA HAS_CONTENTS
 [16]     0xffffffff82697f68->0xffffffff826c807c at 0x01897f68: .orc_lookup ALLOC
 [17]     0xffffffff826c9000->0xffffffff826ca000 at 0x018c9000: .vvar ALLOC LOAD DATA HAS_CONTENTS
 [18]     0x00000000->0x0002b318 at 0x01a00000: .data..percpu ALLOC LOAD RELOC DATA HAS_CONTENTS
 [19]     0xffffffff826f6000->0xffffffff82764674 at 0x01af6000: .init.text ALLOC LOAD RELOC READONLY CODE HAS_CONTENTS
 [20]     0xffffffff82764674->0xffffffff8276500c at 0x01b64674: .altinstr_aux ALLOC LOAD RELOC READONLY CODE HAS_CONTENTS
 [21]     0xffffffff82766000->0xffffffff8284ccb0 at 0x01b66000: .init.data ALLOC LOAD RELOC DATA HAS_CONTENTS
 [22]     0xffffffff8284ccb0->0xffffffff8284ccd0 at 0x01c4ccb0: .x86_cpu_dev.init ALLOC LOAD RELOC READONLY DATA HAS_CONTENTS
 [23]     0xffffffff8284ccd0->0xffffffff8286ba8c at 0x01c4ccd0: .parainstructions ALLOC LOAD RELOC READONLY DATA HAS_CONTENTS
 [24]     0xffffffff8286ba90->0xffffffff828709bb at 0x01c6ba90: .altinstructions ALLOC LOAD RELOC READONLY DATA HAS_CONTENTS
 [25]     0xffffffff828709bb->0xffffffff82871f93 at 0x01c709bb: .altinstr_replacement ALLOC LOAD RELOC READONLY CODE HAS_CONTENTS
 [26]     0xffffffff82871f98->0xffffffff82872060 at 0x01c71f98: .iommu_table ALLOC LOAD RELOC READONLY DATA HAS_CONTENTS
 [27]     0xffffffff82872060->0xffffffff82872088 at 0x01c72060: .apicdrivers ALLOC LOAD RELOC DATA HAS_CONTENTS
 [28]     0xffffffff82872088->0xffffffff82872a81 at 0x01c72088: .exit.text ALLOC LOAD RELOC READONLY CODE HAS_CONTENTS
 [29]     0xffffffff82873000->0xffffffff8287a000 at 0x01c73000: .smp_locks ALLOC LOAD RELOC READONLY DATA HAS_CONTENTS
 [30]     0xffffffff8287a000->0xffffffff8287b000 at 0x01c7a000: .data_nosave ALLOC LOAD DATA HAS_CONTENTS
 [31]     0xffffffff8287b000->0xffffffff82a00000 at 0x01c7b000: .bss ALLOC
 [32]     0xffffffff82a00000->0xffffffff82a2c000 at 0x01c7b000: .brk ALLOC
 [33]     0x00000000->0x0000001c at 0x01c7b000: .comment READONLY HAS_CONTENTS
 [34]     0x00000000->0x000276c0 at 0x01c7b020: .debug_aranges RELOC READONLY HAS_CONTENTS
 [35]     0x00000000->0x0b2ba185 at 0x01ca26e0: .debug_info RELOC READONLY HAS_CONTENTS
 [36]     0x00000000->0x005172ad at 0x0cf5c865: .debug_abbrev READONLY HAS_CONTENTS
 [37]     0x00000000->0x012752a1 at 0x0d473b12: .debug_line RELOC READONLY HAS_CONTENTS
 [38]     0x00000000->0x0024d428 at 0x0e6e8db8: .debug_frame RELOC READONLY HAS_CONTENTS
 [39]     0x00000000->0x002d5379 at 0x0e9361e0: .debug_str READONLY HAS_CONTENTS
 [40]     0x00000000->0x00d028ae at 0x0ec0b559: .debug_loc RELOC READONLY HAS_CONTENTS
 [41]     0x00000000->0x00d46440 at 0x0f90de10: .debug_ranges RELOC READONLY HAS_CONTENTS
gdb-peda$ c
Continuing.
(finishes without crashing)
```

**EDIT**: To be sure that the memory is unmapped, I tried to mmap it with the following userspace test according to @Tsyvarev's answer. Oddly, my program doesn't crash even in this case...

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

int main() {
    struct stat s;
    int in = open("aaa", O_RDONLY | O_RSYNC);
    fstat (in, &s);
    int size = s.st_size;
    char* ptr = mmap(NULL, size, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, in, 0);
    int out = open("/dev/ebbchar",O_WRONLY);
    printf("Written = %d", write(out, ptr, size));
    close(in);
    close(out);
    return 0;
}
```

---

Note: the full PoC code can be found below ([context there](http://derekmolloy.ie/writing-a-linux-kernel-module-part-2-a-character-device/))

```c
/**
 * @file   ebbchar.c
 * @author Derek Molloy
 * @date   7 April 2015
 * @version 0.1
 * @brief   An introductory character driver to support the second article of my series on
 * Linux loadable kernel module (LKM) development. This module maps to /dev/ebbchar and
 * comes with a helper C program that can be run in Linux user space to communicate with
 * this the LKM.
 * @see http://www.derekmolloy.ie/ for a full description and follow-up descriptions.
 */

#include <linux/init.h>           // Macros used to mark up functions e.g. __init __exit
#include <linux/module.h>         // Core header for loading LKMs into the kernel
#include <linux/device.h>         // Header to support the kernel Driver Model
#include <linux/kernel.h>         // Contains types, macros, functions for the kernel
#include <linux/fs.h>             // Header for the Linux file system support
#include <linux/uaccess.h>          // Required for the copy to user function
#define  DEVICE_NAME "ebbchar"    ///< The device will appear at /dev/ebbchar using this value
#define  CLASS_NAME  "ebb"        ///< The device class -- this is a character device driver

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");            ///< The license type -- this affects available functionality
MODULE_AUTHOR("Derek Molloy");    ///< The author -- visible when you use modinfo
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("A simple Linux char driver for the BBB");  ///< The description -- see modinfo
MODULE_VERSION("0.1");            ///< A version number to inform users

static int    majorNumber;                  ///< Stores the device number -- determined automatically
static char   message[256] = {0};           ///< Memory for the string that is passed from userspace
static short  size_of_message;              ///< Used to remember the size of the string stored
static int    numberOpens = 0;              ///< Counts the number of times the device is opened
static struct class*  ebbcharClass  = NULL; ///< The device-driver class struct pointer
static struct device* ebbcharDevice = NULL; ///< The device-driver device struct pointer

// The prototype functions for the character driver -- must come before the struct definition
static int     dev_open(struct inode *, struct file *);
static int     dev_release(struct inode *, struct file *);
static ssize_t dev_read(struct file *, char *, size_t, loff_t *);
static ssize_t dev_write(struct file *, const char *, size_t, loff_t *);

/** @brief Devices are represented as file structure in the kernel. The file_operations structure from
 *  /linux/fs.h lists the callback functions that you wish to associated with your file operations
 *  using a C99 syntax structure. char devices usually implement open, read, write and release calls
 */
static struct file_operations fops =
{
   .open = dev_open,
   .read = dev_read,
   .write = dev_write,
   .release = dev_release,
};

/** @brief The LKM initialization function
 *  The static keyword restricts the visibility of the function to within this C file. The __init
 *  macro means that for a built-in driver (not a LKM) the function is only used at initialization
 *  time and that it can be discarded and its memory freed up after that point.
 *  @return returns 0 if successful
 */
static int __init ebbchar_init(void){
   printk(KERN_INFO "EBBChar: Initializing the EBBChar LKM\n");

   // Try to dynamically allocate a major number for the device -- more difficult but worth it
   majorNumber = register_chrdev(0, DEVICE_NAME, &fops);
   if (majorNumber<0){
      printk(KERN_ALERT "EBBChar failed to register a major number\n");
      return majorNumber;
   }
   printk(KERN_INFO "EBBChar: registered correctly with major number %d\n", majorNumber);

   // Register the device class
   ebbcharClass = class_create(THIS_MODULE, CLASS_NAME);
   if (IS_ERR(ebbcharClass)){                // Check for error and clean up if there is
      unregister_chrdev(majorNumber, DEVICE_NAME);
      printk(KERN_ALERT "Failed to register device class\n");
      return PTR_ERR(ebbcharClass);          // Correct way to return an error on a pointer
   }
   printk(KERN_INFO "EBBChar: device class registered correctly\n");

   // Register the device driver
   ebbcharDevice = device_create(ebbcharClass, NULL, MKDEV(majorNumber, 0), NULL, DEVICE_NAME);
   if (IS_ERR(ebbcharDevice)){               // Clean up if there is an error
      class_destroy(ebbcharClass);           // Repeated code but the alternative is goto statements
      unregister_chrdev(majorNumber, DEVICE_NAME);
      printk(KERN_ALERT "Failed to create the device\n");
      return PTR_ERR(ebbcharDevice);
   }
   printk(KERN_INFO "EBBChar: device class created correctly\n"); // Made it! device was initialized
   return 0;
}

/** @brief The LKM cleanup function
 *  Similar to the initialization function, it is static. The __exit macro notifies that if this
 *  code is used for a built-in driver (not a LKM) that this function is not required.
 */
static void __exit ebbchar_exit(void){
   device_destroy(ebbcharClass, MKDEV(majorNumber, 0));     // remove the device
   class_unregister(ebbcharClass);                          // unregister the device class
   class_destroy(ebbcharClass);                             // remove the device class
   unregister_chrdev(majorNumber, DEVICE_NAME);             // unregister the major number
   printk(KERN_INFO "EBBChar: Goodbye from the LKM!\n");
}

/** @brief The device open function that is called each time the device is opened
 *  This will only increment the numberOpens counter in this case.
 *  @param inodep A pointer to an inode object (defined in linux/fs.h)
 *  @param filep A pointer to a file object (defined in linux/fs.h)
 */
static int dev_open(struct inode *inodep, struct file *filep){
   numberOpens++;
   printk(KERN_INFO "EBBChar: Device has been opened %d time(s)\n", numberOpens);
   return 0;
}

/** @brief This function is called whenever device is being read from user space i.e. data is
 *  being sent from the device to the user. In this case is uses the copy_to_user() function to
 *  send the buffer string to the user and captures any errors.
 *  @param filep A pointer to a file object (defined in linux/fs.h)
 *  @param buffer The pointer to the buffer to which this function writes the data
 *  @param len The length of the b
 *  @param offset The offset if required
 */
static ssize_t dev_read(struct file *filep, char *buffer, size_t len, loff_t *offset){
   int error_count = 0;
   // copy_to_user has the format ( * to, *from, size) and returns 0 on success
   error_count = copy_to_user(buffer, message, size_of_message);

   if (error_count==0){            // if true then have success
      printk(KERN_INFO "EBBChar: Sent %d characters to the user\n", size_of_message);
      return (size_of_message=0);  // clear the position to the start and return 0
   }
   else {
      printk(KERN_INFO "EBBChar: Failed to send %d characters to the user\n", error_count);
      return -EFAULT;              // Failed -- return a bad address message (i.e. -14)
   }
}

/** @brief This function is called whenever the device is being written to from user space i.e.
 *  data is sent to the device from the user. The data is copied to the message[] array in this
 *  LKM using the sprintf() function along with the length of the string.
 *  @param filep A pointer to a file object
 *  @param buffer The buffer to that contains the string to write to the device
 *  @param len The length of the array of data that is being passed in the const char buffer
 *  @param offset The offset if required
 */
static ssize_t dev_write(struct file *filep, const char *buffer, size_t len, loff_t *offset){
   sprintf(message, "%s(%zu letters)", buffer, len);   // appending received string with its length
   size_of_message = strlen(message);                 // store the length of the stored message
   printk(KERN_INFO "EBBChar: Received %zu characters from the user\n", len);
   return len;
}

/** @brief The device release function that is called whenever the device is closed/released by
 *  the userspace program
 *  @param inodep A pointer to an inode object (defined in linux/fs.h)
 *  @param filep A pointer to a file object (defined in linux/fs.h)
 */
static int dev_release(struct inode *inodep, struct file *filep){
   printk(KERN_INFO "EBBChar: Device successfully closed\n");
   return 0;
}

/** @brief A module must use the module_init() module_exit() macros from linux/init.h, which
 *  identify the initialization function at insertion time and the cleanup function (as
 *  listed above)
 */
module_init(ebbchar_init);
module_exit(ebbchar_exit);
```

Comment: As soon as you start dealing with different permissions and memory spaces, the concept of normal C UB and IDB break down.

Comment: @ThomasJager While correct, that doesn't answer my question. I still have no clue why I can read a non-mmapped userspace pointer (low address) from a kernel module (high address) in one environment. What could lead to such a weird behavior?

Answer (score 1):

**Direct access** from the kernel's code to the user space memory is **bad** because of two possible scenarios:

1. Accessed memory could be not belonging to the process, because a **user** space code **passes wrong pointer** to the system call (by error or intentionally).
2. Accessed memory could belong to the process, but currently being **not mapped**.

In both cases **page fault** will be triggered, and, because the fault is caused by the *kernel* code, the system treats this fault as a **kernel error**.

Correct access to the user space memory - via `copy_to_user`/`copy_from_user` - handles these these scenarios *gracefully*:

1. If the memory doesn't belong to the user space process, a `copy_*_user` function returns an error indicator.
2. If the memory belongs to the user space process, a `copy_*_user` function makes sure it is mapped during the access.

So, for demonstrate why direct access to user space memory is bad, you may trigger above scenarios:

1. Pass invalid pointer (e.g. NULL) to the `write` system call and observe that the kernel crashes instead of returning an error code.
2. Pass correct pointer to currently *non-mapped* memory to the `write` system call and observe that the kernel crashes instead of correctly accessing the memory.

   Non-mapped pointer could be obtained by opening some (other) file and `mmap`-ing its content: For most filesystems `mmap` returns initially non-mapped memory.

   **Clarification**: successful `mmap()` call returns pointer to the memory **belonging to the user process**. But this memory *could* be **non-mapped** at this time. The first access to the memory (from user space code) will trigger a page fault, and during it the memory becomes mapped.

Comment: Interesting answer. But, in my case I test my code using `# echo 'test'>/dev/ebbchar`. Thus, unless I miss something, my buffer is not mmapped. And, since I drectly access it (without `copy_*_user`) I **should** have a crash. And weirdly, this in not the case in 1 VM...

Comment: It doesn't have to be mmapp()ed, it has to be in physical memory.

Comment: @MaximeB.: "Thus, unless I miss something, my buffer is not mmapped." - The buffer is allocated by `cat` program, so it **belongs to the process's memory** and *normally* is *mapped*. (I have write "normally" because no one can be sure about that). As opposite, the memory region returned by `mmap` system call, while also belonging to the process's memory, is *normally unmapped* before it is accessed.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Sorry, I had misunderstood your answer. With this clarification it's way better. I tried with a mmap but i still don't have a crash using mmap... I Edit my post to show this.

Comment: Yes, your current code reflects my suggestion. So, for demonstrate the scenario 2 `mmap` approach doesn't work. And I don't know why...

Comment: It seems lastest kernel woudnt crash for user context