# how to use 'copy_to_user' with index to copy by chunks?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module, device-driver

I have a big data in the kernel (1GB+), I want to copy it to the user by chunks.

```
int i=0;
while (myBuffer) {
  copy_to_user(userBuffer + 64*i, (void *) myBuffer, 64)
  myBuffer = newData();
  i++;
}
```

how can I do the (+ 64*i) in kernel mode.. is it legal?
I mean, when I send a buff from user to kernel, kernel want to fill it with data using 'copy_to_user' but kernel will use 'copy_to_user' several times to same userBuff, each time to different place of it.
example:
callback:

```
getMyData(char* userBuff){
  copy_to_user(userBuff, 'H', 1);
  copy_to_user(userBuff+1, 'o', 1);
  copy_to_user(userBuff+2, 'w', 1);
  copy_to_user(userBuff+3, ' ', 1);
  copy_to_user(userBuff+4, 'a', 1);
  copy_to_user(userBuff+5, 'r', 1);
  copy_to_user(userBuff+6, 'e', 1);
}
```

user calls:

```
getMydata(myBuff);
print("%s",myBuff);
```

user expects to print:
   How are

is it possible? its not the same memory...

Comment: "how can I do the +index in kernel mode" - I don't understand that question. Could you be more detailed in the question post? What is the problem with the current code?

Comment: "how can I do the (+ 64*i) in kernel mode.. is it legal?" - Yes, the expression `userBuffer + 64*i` is completely legal and addresses different chunks in the `userBuffer`. And you may call `copy_to_user` inside the single function as many times as you want.

Comment: thanks for the answer, so why do I need "copy_to_user" function? why not to just use memset?

Comment: "why do I need "copy_to_user" function? why not to just use memset?"  - See that my answer to the recent related question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59759822/3440745.